# Fail to connect camera service in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, surfaceview

I am making an video app in kotlin and making my own camera using surfaceview. But whenever I run my app its showing white screen and the buttons which I have added. Its returning an error

```
E/SurfaceView: Exception configuring surface
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
        at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:519)
        at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:383)
        at com.example.videoapp.Chooses.surfaceCreated(Chooses.kt:174)
        at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface(SurfaceView.java:663)
        at android.view.SurfaceView$2.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:143)
```

and its saying that the error is from this code

```
override fun surfaceCreated(holder: SurfaceHolder?) {
    println("onsurfacecreated")
    if (usecamera) {
        camera = Camera.open()
        try {
            camera?.setPreviewDisplay(holder)

            camera?.startPreview()
            previewRunning = true
        } catch (e: IOException) {

            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

}
```

and here is my manifest file permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Are you requesting camera permissions from the user?

Comment: Yes but its showing only white screen